# jQuery get shown div id

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have the following code:

```
<div class="sequence-container"> 
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.sequence-container div:first').show(); // show first on load

    $('.next').click(function() {
        var $next = $('.sequence-container div:visible').next();
        if ($next.length) {
        $('.sequence-container div').hide();
            $next.show();
        }
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
        var $prev = $('.sequence-container div:visible').prev();
        if ($prev.length) {
            $('.sequence-container div').hide();
            $prev.show();
        }
    });

});
```

This, very nicely, allows a user to move back and forth through divs.  However, what I'd like to do, is bring back the `ID` of the `div` that is currently being shown.  I'm struggling - any suggestions?

Comment: can we have jsfiddle??

Comment: Use `.attr` method like `$('.sequence-container div:visible').attr('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$("div:visible").attr("id");
```

It will select the `div` which is visible

Comment: I hang my head in shame...should have spotted it was that easy.  Thank you @Karna

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `attr()` function will allow you to retrieve the `id` value, like this:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Note: `$(this)` refers to the DIV of your jQuery selector.

Comment: Thanks Karl - appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to this part:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var $curr = $('.sequence-container div:visible');
    var id = $curr.attr('id');
    var $next = $curr.next();
    if ($next.length) {
        $('.sequence-container div').hide();
        $next.show();
    }
});
```